# Two variables if empty else other

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Sorry i am a noob in PHP and need help. I have two variables

```
<?php echo $LOGO ?>
<?php echo $TITLE ?>
```

So i need to make that if LOGO is empty the script must show title, but if a logo is set than it must show only the logo.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Just to make things clear, you want to display $LOGO when $TITLE is empty?

Comment: 0_o `echo` what you want to `echo`. Don't `echo` what you don't want to `echo`.

Comment: @Martijn: IMHO I thing he wants to display `$LOGO` if `$TITLE` is not empty, but I can't tell it for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo (empty($LOGO) ? $TITLE : $LOGO) ?>
```

will show $TITLE if $LOGO is empty. Otherwise will only show $LOGO.

This operator is called the [ternary operator](http://phpmaster.com/using-the-ternary-operator/).

`empty` works like this:

```
The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Comment: Come onnnnnn Reversal badge!

Comment: That works if LOGO is set but if its empty its show nothing.

Comment: Then title isn't set.

Comment: It is set, becouse it shows if i post <?php echo $TITLE ?>

Comment: Is $LOGO set to a string like `' '` where there are spaces?