# If one variable empty than other variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Sorry i am a noob in PHP and need help. I have two variables

```
<?php echo $LOGO ?>
<?php echo $TITLE ?>
```

So i need to make that if LOGO is empty the script must show title, but if a logo is set than it must show only the logo.

Many Thanks!

Comment: You just posted this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067968/two-variables-if-empty-else-other) and it was already closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($LOGO)){ 
   echo $TITLE;
}else{
  echo $LOGO;
}
```

Or even:

```
echo (empty($LOGO) ? $TITLE : $LOGO);
```

That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

```
<?php echo empty($LOGO) ? $TITLE : $LOGO; ?>
```